# Typescript: Prevent unexpected usage of object[index]

Tags: typescript

I was surprised to notice that typescript is ok with the following code:

```
interface IFoo {
  bar: string;
}

const foo: IFoo = {bar: 'bar'};

console.log(
  foo['anything'] // I'd like typescript to prevent this
);
```

Is there a way to prevent usage of [] accessor when not expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent usage of [] accessor when not expected?

If you want an error to be thrown you could enable the [`noImplicitAny` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), which would result in the following error:

> Element implicitly has an `any` type because type `IFoo` has no index signature.

Comment: Ok, that's why I was surprised. I usually activate `noImplicitAny` by default. Unfortunately, I'm not ready to activate it on my current project.

Comment: Here is a typescript issue that gives insights on this design choice: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7660

Comment: @TomEsterez - Great, thanks for the link. I was wondering why it was implemented that way as well.